# Возможно ли открывать на телефоне например игру, или заходить в галерею находясь в моем приложении?

Tags: c#, android, unity3d, augmented-reality

я недавно начал заниматься программированием, и пока не имею достаточно опыта - поэтому прошу помочь Вас...

я использую Unity 2020, и возникла задача открывать игры находящиеся на телефоне, галерею например и прочие приложения которые есть на телефоне( не ссылку в интернете открывать, а именно приложение в телефоне), у меня есть код, который делает возможным управлять например браузером, находящимся в сцене, при этом это все происходит в моем приложении, но мне все же хотелось узнать, возможно ли подобное, только не со страницами в интернете, а с самими приложениями на смартфоне...
Спасибо заранее!

Comment: В Xamarin точно можно, значит и в Unity есть способ, но я его не знаю.

Comment: спасибо за Вашу готовность помогать! надеюсь, в Unity тоже есть способ...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51460822/unity-android-intents

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное!!!